# Mocking COM Interfaces using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, com, rhino-mocks

I have a COM library that I have to reference in my app and I am trying to mock its interfaces.

I am getting exceptions when I am doing this `MockRepository.GenerateMock<IAmAComInterface>();`

I don't get exceptions when I do this: `MockRepository.GenerateDynamicMockWithRemoting<IAmAComInterface>();` but none of my expectations are verifying.

Am I doing something wrong?

For now, I have a bunch of wrappers for all of my COM interfaces and I am mocking them, but I would really like to not have to wrap everything.

**EDIT:**
Exceptions with GenerateMock:
 `System.TypeLoadException`
With the message of:
`The type is marked as eligible for type equivalence, but either it has generic parameters, or it is not a structure, COM imported interface, enumeration, or delegate.`

When using GenerateDynamicMockWithRemoting test failure always says Expected: 1 Actual: 0 for any expectations on the COM interface.

Using Rhino.Mocks 3.6.

Comment: @Wim Coenen Edited to include exceptions and more details.

Comment: Are these COM interfaces created in .NET and designed for export to COM?  Or are they COM objects with generated .NET type libraries (via tlbimp)?

Comment: @Patrick Steele They are COM objects with generated .NET type libraries via tlbimp (VS 2010 if that version makes any difference)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue with .NET 4.0's "Type Equivalence".  See this for more details: http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=254

The fix (as noted above) is easy by adding:

```
Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.AttributesToAvoidReplicating.Add(typeof (TypeIdentifierAttribute));
```

To your unit test.

Comment: Impossible for me to call this due to this (or similar) error: Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.AttributesToAvoidReplicating' exists in both '...Castle.Core.dll' and '...Rhino.Mocks.dll'

Comment: @PandaWood - See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095221/how-to-resolve-castle-windsor-and-moq-version-conflicts-for-castle-core-assembly

Comment: This is brilliant!

I was having issue with hosting WCF service from the mocked objects similar to explained here  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rhinomocks/8PT3mLYWxVo/ZXVnBDjt-dkJ

but using your example this work very well

Comment: one issue I encountered while doing some thorough testing that if you have generated the mock for a class/interface before the statements to avoid attributes than subsequent mock generation for the same class/interface do not respect the statements and returns the mock object with attributes.

So make sure that the "avoid statements" are the very first statements executed before any mock generation.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by this solution (from question [How to test a COM dependent object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223991/how-to-test-a-com-dependent-object-in-c-sharp)): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333388/185498

> Try to set "Embed Interop Types" to FALSE for assembly that contains COM interface.