# Rhino Mocks & NUnit with VSTO 2010 error

Tags: mocking, vsto

Has anyone implemented TDD with VSTO 2010 using Rhino Mocks and NUnit?

Is mocking possible with Office COM objects?

I am getting the following error:

System.TypeLoadException

Could not load type 'ApplicationProxy1de359cb29054a3a9f7c0da38e8ee0cc' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The type is marked as eligible for type equivalence, but either it has generic parameters, or it is not a structure, COM imported interface, enumeration, or delegate.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to test a COM dependent object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223991/how-to-test-a-com-dependent-object-in-c) - this problem occurred with [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) as well but is supposed to be [fixed on the trunk](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=254). Like @Gutzofter, I'd recommend creating your own interface wrapper for the COM object.

Comment: So are you saying I must write my own wrappers for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint?

Comment: @alex - I wouldn't wrap the whole thing. You're going to need to test your actual COM code manually (did it create the PowerPoint correctly?). Write your class that calls the interop, then add an interface for your class. Mock that. This has the advantage that it hides the implementation; if you later license a third-party library to create the PowerPoint, your interface doesn't need to change (and neither does your client code).

Answer (score 0):

I've been happily mocking Excel objects with NSubstitute for a few weeks now.  Try that?